# Windows XP Ubuntu Installer (version 11.10) error dialog - Permission Denied

Tags: 11.10, installation, windows, permissions

When installing Ubuntu 11.10 on Windows XP (2nd option in installer), the install failed with popup.  How can I fix this?

[image]

Here is the contents of file "C:\Documents and Settings\Keith\Local Settings\Temp\wubi-11.10-rev241.log".  I only pasted the last few lines because of the question size limit.

```
\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp is a valid Xubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp is a valid Xubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Xubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether Y:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
    03-25 22:29 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: Y:\
    03-25 22:29 INFO   root: Running the installer...
    03-25 22:29 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
    03-25 22:29 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=C:, installation_size=18000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=en_US, locale=en_US.UTF-8, username=keith
    03-25 22:29 INFO   root: Received settings
    03-25 22:29 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
    03-25 22:29 INFO   WindowsBackend: Installing into C:\ubuntu
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished select_target_dir
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_dir_structure...
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_dir_structure
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_target_dir...
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller Y:\wubi.exe -> C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi UninstallString C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi InstallationDir C:\ubuntu
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayName Ubuntu
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayIcon C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayVersion 11.10-rev241
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi Publisher Ubuntu
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi URLInfoAbout http://www.ubuntu.com
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi HelpLink http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\data\custom-installation -> C:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\winboot -> C:\ubuntu\winboot
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\Keith\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl1.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
    03-25 22:29 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
    03-25 22:32 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 13] Permission denied
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
    03-25 22:32 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
    03-25 22:32 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
    03-25 22:32 ERROR  root: [Errno 13] Permission denied
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
      File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
      File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
      File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 120, in select_task
      File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
    03-25 22:32 ERROR  TaskList: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 579, in get_iso
      File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 565, in use_iso
    AttributeError: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
    03-25 22:32 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
    03-25 22:32 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first followed these instructions from the forum in this link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10416349

"I downloaded Virtual CloneDrive (google it - its freeware) When I installed Virtual CloneDrive, I associated the .iso files with it and no others. I then ran the .iso file that I originally downloaded to make my disc, directly from my Program Files folder by double-clicking. It should be mounted and launch as a virtual drive and run like the disc but without using the disc. I think the access denied error has something to do with the disc drive but I was unable to fix it."

**However**, note that the disc was bad that I burned.  The procedure above will work, BUT only in Windows.  Once you reboot and Ubuntu finishes installing, you'll get green errors (similar to the beginning of the movie The Matrix.

I had started burning the image with ImgBurn, and then stopped the burning process.  Then I used the same disc and re-burned the same image.  It said it completed successfully.  **When I burned a brand new disc, and verified the disc, and used that one to install Ubuntu, it worked perfectly.**